# How do I loop through all pixels on a TBitmap and get the pixel colors?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to loop through all the pixels on a `TBitmap` image and then display all the colors in a `TMemo` component.

I have a simple GUI with a `TImage` that contains the image that I want to loop through all pixels with and then a `TButon` that has a click event that will do the looping. Then also obviously the `TMemo` to display them into:

[image: Delphi Form Designer]

I've tried a lot of different code to loop through the Bitmap Pixels, but here's the latest code that I tried:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BitmapData: TBitmapData;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  var Bitmap := Image1.Bitmap;
  try
    if Bitmap.Map(TMapAccess.ReadWrite, BitmapData) then
    begin
      try
        for var Y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
        begin
          for var X := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
          begin
            var PixelColor := BitmapData.GetPixel(X, Y);
            Memo1.Lines.Add('X: ' + X.ToString + ' | Y: ' + Y.ToString + ' | ' + AlphaColorToString(PixelColor))
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Bitmap.Unmap(BitmapData);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The above code gives me an `out of memory` exception:

> Project raised exception class EOutOfMemory with message 'Out of memory'.

---

Can someone help me with code to loop through each pixel on a TBitmap and get the `TAlphaColor` of that pixel please?

Comment: For VCL I would have suggested using https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ScanLine. But in FMX this looks like the suggested way to go. I would however put the same trust in inline variables as Embarcadero does in their examples (namely none) and eliminate all of those, especially the ones with type inference as that goes wrong even more often.

Comment: I agree with Sherlock70. The compiler should recognise that only one PixelColor variable is needed, for example, but it may be creating one for every loop iteration. So get rid of those and eliminate this as a potential source of your problems and come back if it does not help.

Answer (score 4):

Although it doesn't surprise me, that you get an out of memory error, there is a more severe problem in your code. The `out of memory` error you avoid by not printing out useless data in a `TMemo`. There might of course be very good reasons to print out a small amount of pixel colors. Your code to print the colors, works, if you just keep it from exhausting memory.

The more severe problem though is that you delete the `Image1.bitmap`, although `Image1` is the owner and  wants to hold on to it.

Remove `Bitmap.Free` from the end of your `Button1Click` procedure, as well as the outermost `try..finally..end`. The role of your `var Bitmap` is only to act as a convenient local reference to the `Image1.Bitmap`, not to take ownership.